# Android fragment bundle only get one arg

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, bundle

I want to pass multiple values from my fragment to the other fragment.

This is what i do in fragment A:

```
mCallback.passData("title","test");
```

Activity:

[image: Activity]

Fragment B:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
    if(args != null){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), args.getString(NAME_RECEIVE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), args.getString(TITLE_RECEIVE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

But i only get one argument from my bundle

Thanks @cricket_007

I was passing 2 times the same string for NAME_RECEIVE and TITLE_RECEIVE:

```
final static String TITLE_RECEIVE = "data_receive";
final static String NAME_RECEIVE = "data_receive";
```

Comment: what is `NAME_RECEIVE ` and `TITEL_RECEIVE `, they should not be the same

Comment: That's not the best way the instantiate a fragment. You should be probably using the static `newInstance(String arg1, String arg2)` function. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment

Comment: Might want to fix your TITEL typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Strings are the same.

Look at your debugger, and you see `Bundle[{data_received="test"}]`, meaning that `NAME_RECEIVE` is the exact same value of `TITEL_RECEIVE`, which is `"data_received"`

Also, never Toast two things at once. You'll only see one pop-up box.

Try `Log` instead.

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
if(args != null){
    Log.d(NAME_RECEIVE, args.getString(NAME_RECEIVE));
    Log.d(TITEL_RECEIVE, args.getString(TITEL_RECEIVE));
}
```

Additional reference for "proper" Fragment creation: [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007. Indeed i was using  this in fragment B: 
    final static String TITLE_RECEIVE = "data_receive";
    final static String NAME_RECEIVE = "data_receive";